# start chromium on raspberry pi in kiosk mode using systemd service instead of through LXDE-pi/autostart

Tags: chromium, kiosk, systemd-startup

As many people, i'm looking to use my pi as a kiosk. I have managed to get everything running when starting the kiosk.

my kiosk.sh script, which works fine

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="http://127.0.0.1"
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

unclutter -idle 0.5 -root &

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk $URL &
```

I am able to autostart this script thorugh 
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi

@bash /home/pi/kiosk/kiosk.sh
```

However, when I try the same using a unit file, that does not work. I commented out the last line of autostart before starting the service

```
[Unit]
Description=Chromium Dashboard
Requires=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/pi/kiosk/kiosk.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

this is the output of systemctl status pi@kiosk.service

```
● pi@kiosk.service - Chromium Dashboard
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pi@kiosk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-10-21 20:38:56 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 1417 ExecStart=/home/pi/kiosk/kiosk.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1417 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 21 20:38:55 countdown systemd[1]: Started Chromium Dashboard.
Oct 21 20:38:56 countdown systemd[1]: pi@kiosk.service: Succeeded.
```

so I would like to know where I am going wrong here. I should get the same response both ways but I dont.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unit file looks very good for a program to start as service. **systemd** runs services automatically in the background. But your script is sending `unclutter` and `chromium-browser` to the background additional using `&`. After doing that the bash script terminates successful with exit code 0 and that is what `systemctl status` show you with:

```
Process: 1417 ExecStart=/home/pi/kiosk/kiosk.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Everything is OK from the view of systemd but it has lost any control about `chromium-browser` that is running everywhere in the background. You should be able to find it with `ps aux | grep chromium-browser`. If you really want to run it as old-style daemon by sending it to the background you may have a look at `man systemd.service` using `Type=forking` and maybe `PIDFile=` and other things to control forked daemons. But I don't believe that it will work because the commands are wrapped into a bash script and systemd cannot see them.

I would suggest to delete the last two lines from the script and try this Unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Chromium Dashboard
Requires=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
ExecStartPre=/home/pi/kiosk/kiosk.sh
ExecStart=usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk $URL
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

This is only to give an idea how it could work. Of course you have to look how to define `$URL` within the Unit. I don't know your setup. You cannot start a second service **unclutter** e.g. with `ExecStartPre=/full/path/to/unclutter -idle 0.5 -root`. If you need to run it in the background before chromium-browser then you have to make its own Unit and start `kiosk.service` *After* that.

Comment: thank you. with some tweaking this worked perfectly. I ended up running unclutter as  part of /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart and running both an ExecStartPre script (as you suggested) and an ExecStartPost script which takes care of tabbing for me if I want to open multiple pages and automatically tab between them.